# rewriting url for query strings

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, get, query-string

Hi I want To Ask How Can I convert
http://abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id=16
to
http://abc.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id/16
using .htaccess mod_write

```
                RewriteBase /
                Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^comments\.php\?post_referrel_id/([^/]*)$  /comments.php?post_referrel_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What is the link your entering in browser. @user1835722

Comment: this is the link i am entering.......http://blogpakistan.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id=13

Comment: Enter: blogpakistan.tk/comments.php?post_referrel_id/13 @user1835722

Comment: not working........u can check also........

Comment: Cant understand what is the problem. @user1835722

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /` after `RewriteEngine On` @user1835722

Comment: hey i have written  RewriteBase / .......but i to didntunderstand what is the problem......

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule comments.php?(.*)/(.*)/$  /comments.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: i am writing this .htaccess file......RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule comments.php?(.*)/(.*)/$  /comments.php?$1=$2 [L]

Comment: then try `nickhar` and `Samuel Cook` ans

Answer (score 0):

A URL rewrite wouldn't matter in this instance, as your still using query strings. It would make more since to eliminate the Query string all together with something like:

```
http://abc.tk/comments.php/post_referrel_id/16
```

Nevertheless, this can be achieved using .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule comments.php?post_referral_id/(.*)$ /comments.php?post_referral_id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Which will still use the same code, but be recognized by a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^comments\.php\?post_referal_id/([^/]*)$ /comments.php?post_referrel_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If you are testing on Localhost add `RewriteBase /YOUR-WEB-FOLDER` @user1835722

Comment: If running on a Sub-domain add sub-domain to `RewriteBase /sub-domain-name` @user1835722

Comment: Then `RewriteBase /` is OK. @user1835722

Comment: hey i hav updated the question.....i am writing this code but no affect on the query strings........